# Bcrypt npm module error with TravisCI

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Bcrypt is a dependency of mine on a Nodejs app and when running the TravisCI build, this error occurs:

```js
make: Leaving directory `/home/travis/build/IBM-Bluemix/nodejs-MEAN-stack/node_modules/bcrypt/build'

gyp[0m ERR! build error 

gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)

gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)

gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)

gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-63-generic

gyp ERR! command "/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/bin/node" "/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"

gyp ERR! cwd /home/travis/build/IBM-Bluemix/nodejs-MEAN-stack/node_modules/bcrypt

gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.5

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1

gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-63-generic

npm ERR! argv "/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/bin/node" "/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/bin/npm" "install"

npm ERR! node v4.4.5

npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.

npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,

npm ERR! not with npm itself.

npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:

npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild

npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:

npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt

npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:

npm ERR! 

npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt

npm mERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     /home/travis/build/IBM-Bluemix/nodejs-MEAN-stack/npm-debug.log
```

Entire error log here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/144662107/log.txt

Repository here: https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/nodejs-MEAN-stack/tree/production-sample

Answer (score 0):

You could try and replace bcrypt with bcryptjs, which is optimized bcrypt in plain JavaScript with zero dependencies.

Comment: I will see if I can do that